# Python Plotly - 3D-Plot - Change colorscale

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to change the colour scale or the colour of my 3D plot. I need a colour scale in green - yellow - red depending on the z-value.

Approximately like this:

- 0-3 red
- 4-8 yellow
- 9 - 13 green

I managed to change the colour in one of the templates, but I can't get my own colours to work.

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z_data.values)])

fig.update_layout(title='Knochehöhe', font_size = 8, scene = dict(xaxis_title="Y", yaxis_title="X"), width=1000, height=1000) 

fig.update_traces(contours_z=dict(show=True, usecolormap=True,
                                  highlightcolor="limegreen", project_z=True)) # Spiegelung
fig.layout.template = "none"

fig.show()

# here i tried my own colorscale, but I have received an error message "TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()"

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z_data.values)])

fig.update_layout(title='Knochehöhe', font_size = 8, scene = dict(xaxis_title="Y", yaxis_title="X"), 
                  width=1000, height=1000, colorscale=dict([[0, 'green'], [0.5, 'red'], [1.0, 'rgb(0, 0, 255)']])) 


fig.update_traces(contours_z=dict(show=True, usecolormap=True,
                                  highlightcolor="limegreen", project_z=True)) # Spiegelung

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need discrete colors, I believe you can change the `colorscale` to:

```
color_continuous_scale=[(0.0, "red"),   (3.0, "red"),
                        (3.0, "yellow"), (8.0, "Yellow"),
                        (8.0, "green"),  (15.0, "gree")])
```

Comment: for a continuous one, maybe use the built-in `RdYlGn` "diverging" colors scale